# pandas_udf in pyspark3.0.0 get unexpected wrong

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I followed the example in [spark website](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html), but it went wrong, my code is in below:

```
import pandas as pd

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.pandas.functions import pandas_udf


class SparkBase(object):
    def __init__(self, master="local[*]", app_name="SparkBase"):
        _conf = SparkConf().setMaster(master).setAppName(app_name)
        _conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", True)
        _conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.fallback.enabled", True)
        self.sc = SparkContext().getOrCreate(conf=_conf)
        self.spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=_conf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()


@pandas_udf("col1 string, col2 long")
def func(s1: pd.Series, s2: pd.Series, s3: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    s3["col2"] = s1 + s2.str.len()
    return s3


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark_base = SparkBase()
    df = spark_base.spark.createDataFrame([[1, "a string", ("a nested string",)]],
                                          "long_c long, str_c string, struct_c struct<col1: string>")
    df.show()
```

the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/otherproj/localpyspark/pyspark3/sparkbase.py", line 24, in <module>
    def func(s1: pd.Series, s2: pd.Series, s3: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\pandas\functions.py", line 426, in _create_pandas_udf
    return _create_udf(f, returnType, evalType)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\udf.py", line 43, in _create_udf
    return udf_obj._wrapped()
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\udf.py", line 204, in _wrapped
    wrapper.returnType = self.returnType
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\udf.py", line 94, in returnType
    self._returnType_placeholder = _parse_datatype_string(self._returnType)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 822, in _parse_datatype_string
    raise e
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 812, in _parse_datatype_string
    return from_ddl_schema(s)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 804, in from_ddl_schema
    sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.fromDDL(type_str).json())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
```

And if I annotate the `func` function, it can run successfully. Where is wrong with it? Is it a bug in spark3.0.0?